# How to run Tomcat on eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, server

I have an issue with running Tomcat on my eclipse. My professors advise and some online articles said to find "Server" and "Runtime Environment" in the Preference or Window menu, but none of those first two exist on my eclipse, and have no clue what to do. If you know how to solve this, please let me know.

I followed my instructor's instructions and googled the same topic, but no appropriate solutions were found.

Comment: You might have downloaded the wrong "edition" of eclipse: There are several pre-packaged environments, and you'd need the one [for Java and Web Developers](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/) or one that includes the same plugins and others

Comment: Instructions in https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_install_WTP.3F have been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Eclipse EE](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2022-03/r/eclipse-ide-enterprise-java-and-web-developers) - if not already so - should solve this.
(won't work with [Eclipse IDE for Java Developers](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2022-03/r/eclipse-ide-java-developers).)